# Why does the Qt program crash when it is in a path that contains any non-English characters?

Tags: windows, qt, crash, qt5, non-english

my operation system is Windows7 SP1, Qt version is 5.12.0. I built an exe file by VS2017, when I double-click the exe to run, it will crash if its path contains any non-English characters(e.g. Chinese, Korean, Japanese, etc.) The code that triggered the crash is this line—

```
QWebEngineSettings *settings = QWebEngineSettings::defaultSettings();
```

This is the disassembly view when crash

[image]

And this is the stack view when crash

[image]

Does anybody have any idea of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the reason for this problem. The reason is that the version of the Qt dlls which the program runs with(5.14.0) is different from the version I set in the VS2017 for building the program(5.12.0). I'm sorry.